# Is there a selective replace function? Should it be done using a If statement or For loop?

Tags: r, replace, find

I am relatively new to R. I need some help with more of a find and replace function but it is a bit more selective.

The example datasets I am using can be derived through:

```
name_1 <- c("Madeline","Maximillian","Maxon","Mad","Marvin")
value <- c(2.3,3.4,7.5,1.9,16.2)
scoreboard_table <- data.frame(name_1,value)

name_2 <- c("Madeline","Maximillian","Maxon","Mad")
nickname_1 <- c("Mad","Max","M","N/A")
nickname_2 <- c("Madine","Maxim","N/A","N/A")
nickname_table <- data.frame(name_2,nickname_1,nickname_2)
```

I want to replace the name of the scoreboard table with the second nickname. In that case, it would result in scoreboard_table to turn into:

```
name_1 <- c("Madine","Maxim","Maxon","Mad","Marvin")
value <- c(2.3,3.4,7.5,1.9,16.2)
scoreboard_table <- data.frame(name_1,value)
```

I am sure if doing a for loop would be easier or making an if, else statement. How should I go about this overall?

Thank you for the help in advance. It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a join and use `coalesce` to get names from `nickname_2`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(scoreboard_table, nickname_table, by = c('name_1' = 'name_2')) %>%
  transmute(name_1 = coalesce(nickname_2, name_1), 
            value) -> scoreboard_table

scoreboard_table

#  name_1 value
#1 Madine   2.3
#2  Maxim   3.4
#3  Maxon   7.5
#4    Mad   1.9
#5 Marvin  16.2
```

If they are not already change the `"N/A"` values to real `NA` in your data.

```
nickname_table[nickname_table == 'N/A'] <- NA
```

Comment: This would lead some of the names to become NA. How do I avoid this? Should there by like an if statement?

Comment: Can you provide an example to support that claim? It doesn't return `NA` values for the example that you have shared.

Comment: It states that there an "Error in UseMethod("transmute") : 
  no applicable method for 'transmute' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"" causing the transmute half of the code to not work.

Comment: That's strange. Are you using the same data that you have shared in your question? I don't get any such error on that data. Btw, I just noticed that you have used string `"N/A"` values while constructing the dataframe and not the real `NA` values. Change them to actual `NA` values before using the answer.

Comment: OHH that was the problem! Thank you for all the help!